# How to create a php mysql dynamic tree

Tags: php, mysql

How can using php mysql create a dynamic tree for this tables

**tbl_folder**

```
db_id   db_foldername
1       accounting
2       hr
3       it
```

**tbl_subfolder**

```
db_id  db_folderid  db_subfoldername
1        1            xxx
2        1            yyy
3        2            zzz
```

**tbl_childsubfolder**

```
db_id  db_subfolderid db_childsubfoldername
1        1                ffff
2        2                llll
```

**tbl_subchild**

```
db_id    db_childsubfolderid   db_subchildname
1           1                     eee
2           1                     ppp
```

- accounting

  - xxx

    - fff

      - eee
      - ppp
  - yyy

    - lll
- hr

  - zzz
- it

  include("include/connect.php");
      
      
      
      --SELECT--
      $name";
      }
      ?>

  ```
  if(isset($_POST['add'])){
      $foldername=$_POST['txt_name'];
      $select=$_POST['txt_select'];echo $select;
      $explod=explode("-",$select);
      $path=$explod['0'].';'.$explod['1'];
      if($path==";"){$path="";}
      $parent_id=$explod['1'];
      if($foldername==""){echo"enter a name";}
      else{ 
      $insert_query=mysqli_query($conn,"insert into tbl_folders(parent_id,path,name)values('$parent_id','$path','$foldername')")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
          header("location:index.php");
      }
  }


  $sql=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tbl_folders where parent_id='0'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
  while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sql)){
      $name=$row['name'];
      $id=$row['db_id'];
      echo $name;echo"<br/>";
      $sqli=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tbl_folders where parent_id='$id'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sqli)){
       $name=$row['name'];
      $id=$row['db_id'];
      $path=$row['path'];
      $x=explode(";",$path);echo $path;echo"<br/>";
      $pa=$x['1']; 
      echo $name;echo"<br/>";
      $sqli=mysqli_query($conn,"select * from tbl_folders where parent_id='$id' and path='$pa'")or die(mysqli_error($conn));
      while($row=mysqli_fetch_array($sqli)){
           $name=$row['name'];
      $id=$row['db_id'];
      $path=$row['db_path'];    
      echo $name;echo"<br/>";}
      }
  }
  ```

Comment: it`s not necessary to use so many tables... only one table is absolutely enough

Comment: @krasipenkov How can i do it with one table ?!

Comment: @krasipenkov thank you for this important information but if i want to print my tree how can i do that ?!

Comment: @krasipenkov can you please check above what i did it 1- is true the insert method like this? 2- when i want to print the child of parents i can't because in the path i have somthing like this ;8;10 how can i solve it ?

Comment: If you have possibility of changing schema check out this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4048151/what-are-the-options-for-storing-hierarchical-data-in-a-relational-database

Answer (score 1):

**Building the tree**

You can build one table with the following fields:

```
`id (int), parent_id (int), path (vachar), name`
```

id - is the identifier
parent_id - refers to the id of the parent in the same table
path - is the path of parent ids to the given element

Example entries in the table:

```
|id | parent_id | path | name|
-------------------------------
|1  | 0         |      | A   |
-------------------------------
|2  | 1         |;1;   | B   |
-------------------------------
|3  | 2         |;1;2; | C   |
```

where A is the parent, B is child of A, and C is child of B.

In your backend logic you need to have the following:
When you add/edit new item in this table - if it is root parent (with no parents above it) you insert it with `parent_id=0` and `path=''`
When you add/edit new item in this table - if it has parent then you insert it with `parent_id=:idOfParent` and  `path=CONCAT(:parentPath, ';', :idOfParent, ';')`
where `:idOfParent` - is the parent id value and `:parentPath` is the path of the parent which you concatenate with the `;:idOfParent;`
`;` - is the separator for the ids in the path

Path column gives you the advantage of directly getting all the parents of given element without using recursive approaches.
So if you select an item with path ';1;2;3;' and you need the info for the parents also you will have  **1 + 3** SELECT queries in total.

And when deleting an item you can do this:

```
 DELETE FROM table WHERE path LIKE (';:deleteId;')
```

where `:deletedId` is the id of the deleted element. This query will delete all the entries that have deleted item as a parent.

**Visualization of the tree**

you can get the $data with this query

```
'SELECT id, parent_id, path, name FROM table WHERE 1;'
```

But for the test i use the following example array

```
$data = [
    0 => ['id' => 1, 'parent_id' => 0, 'path' => '', 'name' => 'A'],
    1 => ['id' => 2, 'parent_id' => 1, 'path' => ';1;', 'name' => 'B'],
    2 => ['id' => 3, 'parent_id' => 2, 'path' => ';1;2;', 'name' => 'C'],
    3 => ['id' => 4, 'parent_id' => 3, 'path' => ';1;2;3;', 'name' => 'D'],

    4 => ['id' => 5, 'parent_id' => 1, 'path' => ';1;', 'name' => 'E'],
    5 => ['id' => 6, 'parent_id' => 2, 'path' => ';1;2;', 'name' => 'G'],
    6 => ['id' => 7, 'parent_id' => 0, 'path' => '', 'name' => 'H'],
];

$ref = null;
$tree = [];
foreach($data as $item) {
    if($item['path']) {
        $path = ltrim($item['path'], ';');
        $path = rtrim($path, ';');
        $pathArray = explode(';', $path);

        $i = 0;
        foreach($pathArray as $parentId) {
            if($i === 0) {
                if(!isset($tree[$parentId])) {$tree[$parentId] = ['name' => [], 'children' => []];}
                $ref = &$tree[$parentId]['children'];
            }
            else {
                if(!isset($ref[$parentId])) $ref[$parentId] = ['name' => [], 'children' => []];
                $ref = &$ref[$parentId]['children'];
            }
            $i++;
        }

        if($ref !== null) {
            $ref[$item['id']]['name'] = $item['name'];
            $ref[$item['id']]['children'] = [];
        }
    }
    else {
        $tree[$item['id']]['name']     = $item['name'];
        $tree[$item['id']]['children'] = [];
    }
}
```

Output part:

```
print '<pre>';
print_r($tree);
print '</pre>';
```

So here you change the code according to your needs. Print it in the way you want (may be you will need recurrsion to access every tree node)